# Convert an ASP.NET MVC application into a 3 tiered architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hey guys! I'm using ASP.NET MVC to develop an application for a library with Nhibernate. I've already used Repository and I'll add the Injection dependency. I'd like to know what are the different steps and what should I add to convert my app into a 3-tiered architecture? Thanks a lot for your help :).

Comment: Cause I need to separate the different component on different machines. and I have to use dotNet remoting. I don't even know How to sepate them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to break it too you, but it looks like you need to re-write almost every controller to use dotnetremoting.

Traditionally "physical" tiers use a separate sever for website, application services and a database.  This means you cannot open an nhibernate session on the same tier as your controllers.

Comment: I'd think so.  Every database call has to go through a service layer.  That a lot of separate methods to make as well as refactoring  your controllers to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the [nerddiner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) example, or read [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/iteration-1-create-the-application-cs) blog series posts to give an idea.

Comment: I've done those Steps and I've create my application but I need to deployed it in 3 machines and respect the 3-tiered architecture. I don't know how to do that and if there are rules and codes to add. thank you :)